# Externalize grails application configuration to tomcat conf directory

Tags: tomcat, grails

I'm trying to externalize configuration for a grails application.

I've successfully externalized such that configuration file is in user home directory as follows.

```
grails.config.locations = ["file:${userHome}/.conf/${appName}-config.properties"]
```

However, I need to externalize such that configuration file need to be inside `tomcat/conf` directory.

In other non-grails applications, I used to achieve this by specifying config location to be at `${CATALINA_HOME}/conf`.

How can configurations be externalized to a `tomcat/conf` directory in grails?

Comment: Have you tried: grails.config.locations = ["file:${System.env.CATALINA_HOME}/conf/myconfig.properties"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running an application in Tomcat, `catalina.home` and `catalina.base` are available in Java system properties.

So you can use them in your `Config.groovy` file to add a new path to `grails.config.locations`:

```
grails.config.locations = []
def tomcatConfDir = new File("${System.properties['catalina.home']}/conf")
    if (tomcatConfDir.isDirectory()) {
    grails.config.locations << "file:${tomcatConfDir.canonicalPath}/${appName}-config.groovy"
}
```

This is just an example, but it works.

Comment: You should try again. I have added an example in my previous answer.